# Unable to revert Security Patch SUPEE-10570 v1

Tags: patches, magento1.9.2.4, supee-10570

Trying to revert SUPEE-10570v1 to apply SUPEE-10570v2, but I'm unable to revert and receiving this code (I have checked all prior patches and they are the correct versions):

```
app/Mage.php
...
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
Unreverted patch detected!   Ignore -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
app/locale/en_US/Mage_ImportExport.csv
lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
```

Comment: Revert depend upon how you add patch into magento?
* Revert using command if you install through shell
* Need to remove files manually if you have uploaded files.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have v1 or v2 of Patch 9656, if you have v1, revert and install v2 of SUPEE-9767. Then try installing  SUPEE-10570v2. Try git diff the files with a clean repo of your Magento version. Run the patch with

> sh (nameofpatch).sh or ./(nameofpatch).sh

Comment: There is no patch with the number 9656. If you mean SUPEE-9652, there is only one version which I checked in my applied patches file and I do have the correct version. I also have supee-9767v2 already installed. I have 10570v1 installed and trying to revert it so I can apply 10570v2, but it won't revert and having this issue. I also have a development site with the exact same theme and patches and I could revert with no issues. Also, which files am I supposed to do a clean repo of Mage_Catalog, Mage_ImportExport or Sendmail?

Comment: Solved with clean version install of app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv from ver 1.9.3.8.

Comment: @jensusu happy to hear that is solved . Can you tick it as useful answer ?